# Please refute my counterexample

Tags: normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

(My problem is the same as problem 1.4 in [this PDF](http://math.mit.edu/~rbm/iml/Chapter1.pdf).)

---

Some definitions:

Let $\rho_{\alpha,\beta}(\phi) = \sup_{x \in E_n} |x^{\alpha} D^{\beta} \phi(x) |$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are multi-indices and $E_n$ is an $n$-dimensional space. We index $\rho_{\alpha,\beta}$ by $\rho_k$ instead, and define
$$
   \rho = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \frac{\rho_k}{1+\rho_k}.
$$

I wish to show that $\rho$ is a seminorm. Therefore, I need to show it satisfies the three properties

1. $\rho(\phi) \ge 0$; $\rho(\phi) = 0 \not \Leftrightarrow\phi = 0$.
2. $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \rho(c \phi) = |c| \rho(\phi)$.
3. $\rho(\phi+\psi) \le \rho(\phi) + \rho(\psi)$

where $\phi, \psi \in S(E_n)$, the Schwartz class (a.k.a. testing functions).

I believe I've shown 1. and 2., except for the second property mentioned in 1., namely that $\rho= 0 \not\Rightarrow \phi = 0$.

However, my main question is to do with 3. Since $\rho_k$ is a norm, we have $\rho_k(\phi+\psi) \le \rho_k(\phi) + \rho_k(\psi)$. Hence,

\begin{align}
   \rho(\phi + \psi)
   & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \frac{\rho_k(\phi+\psi)}{1+\rho_k(\phi+\psi)} \\
   &\le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \frac{\rho_k(\phi)+\rho_k(\psi)}{1+\rho_k(\phi+\psi)} \\ 
   & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \frac{\rho_k(\phi)}{1+\rho_k(\phi+\psi)} + \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} 2^{-l} \frac{\rho_l(\psi)}{1+\rho_l(\phi+\psi)}.
\end{align}

I wish to show that this last line is less than or equal to the following expression:

$$
   \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} \frac{\rho_k(\phi)}{1+\rho_k(\phi)} + \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} 2^{-l} \frac{\rho_l(\psi)}{1+\rho_l(\psi)}
$$

and the result would follow.

To do this, I would have to show that $\rho_k(\phi) \le \rho_k(\phi+\psi)$ for all $\phi,\psi$. So assume this is true (for the moment).

However, if we take $\psi = -\phi$, then

\begin{align}
   \rho_k(\phi+\psi)
   & = \rho_k(0) \\
   & = 0.
\end{align}

However, $\rho_k(\phi) \ge 0$ for all $\phi$. If our above statement were true, then $0 \le \rho_k(\phi) \le 0 \implies \rho_k(\phi) = 0 \iff \phi \equiv 0$. But this is a contradiction of our assumption. So the statement is not true for all $\phi, \psi$.

---

What is wrong with my counterexample? Is $\rho$ really a seminorm? How can I show this? This seminorm appears to be used consistently across different references.

Comment: If someone could fix my $\not \implies$ and $\not \iff$ that would be great. Not sure what commands I should be using to get nice output.

Comment: Even if your attempted proof can't be fixed, it doesn't imply that the result is false. I suspect you "lost" too much in the inequality in your second line of calculation; ie you are trying to show $a\leq b$ by using $a\leq c$, but actually $c>b$.

Comment: As an alternative to your second line, I suggest showing that $\frac{\rho_k(\phi+\psi)}{1+\rho_k(\phi+\psi)}\leq\frac{\rho_k(\phi)+\rho_k(\psi)}{1+\rho_k(\phi)+\rho_k(\psi)}$.

Comment: You can use `\not\Rightarrow` and `\not\Leftrightarrow`. However, the negation of long versions of these arrows is off, too: `\not\Longleftrightarrow` $\not\Longleftrightarrow$. Also, see this question on TeX.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47063/rightarrow-vs-implies-and-does-not-imply-symbol